# Is there an R function to perform a loop on a large list

Tags: r, data-mining, sentiment-analysis, corpus

I have a 'large list' (a single object consisting of 10 different data frames) of text that I would like to convert to corpuses. I have tried the following code:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  X=get(paste0("DT_text[[",i,"]]"))
  X <-iconv(X$content, to = "utf-8-mac")
  X <- VCorpus(VectorSource(X))
  assign(paste0("DT_text",i,"]]"), X)
  }
```

I then receive an error message saying that **Error in get(paste0("DT_text[[", i, "]]")) :
object 'DT_text[[1]]'** not found. I can perform the view() function on DT_text[[1]], but as it is a tibble is it possible that it does not work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why use `get` and `paste0` instead of `X <- DT_text[[i]]`?

Comment: One of the big advantage of using lists is you *don't* need to use `get` and `assign` - standard R syntax works.

Comment: @manotheshark and Gregor Thomas, thank you both! I am not used to working with lists so I overcomplicated it. The standard R syntax works great :)